# How to store combo box selected item or value as short when it could be null

Tags: c#, combobox

When I try the code below I get a "Specified cast is not valid" error. This happens whether I use selected value or selected item for the combo box.  I need to convert to a short because I'm storing the value of the combo box in a variable as a short.

Why am I getting this error, and what can I do to fix it?

```
    try {
        var a = comboBox?.SelectedItem ?? 0;
        var x = (short)a;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
```

Comment: How are you adding the items to the combobox?

Comment: I am executing a stored procedure to get a DataTable.  The data source for the combo box is the default view for that DataTable.

Comment: You'll need to find out the actual underlying type of `.SelectedItem`. Can you add some debug output and check it? Such as `Debug.WriteLine(comboBox.SelectedItem.GetType().FullName);`

Comment: I tried that, and the type is DataRowView. The selected value type is Int16 but I still need to be able to handle nulls.

Comment: I suppose you could check `SelectedItem` for null and explicitly use `0` if it is, otherwise cast it to `short`. `if (comboBox?.SelectedItem == null) x = 0 else x = (short)comboBox.SelectedItem;` or somesuch.